# Database Synchronization options

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, synchronization, database-connection, microsoft-sync-framework

There is a new windows application to be developed in visual studio 2010. The Clients requested that the application should have a local database on each of their laptops and the database should be synchronized with the central server when they are connected to the office network. The central server is windows server 2003 and the Client PC is windows 2007. Please help me with the answers to the below questions

1. Which version of sql server can be installed in windows server 2003?
2. Methods of synchronization with sql server if MS Access is used as a local database. Is linking of access database to SQL Server is a two way synchronization?
3. Can sql express be used on local to be synchronized with SQl server using microsoft sync framework? If yes please let me know the version of SQL express and SQL Server to be installed.

Please let me know the Pros and cons of the above methods or any alternative solution. I have done a lot of research on this but cannot come to a conclusion. Kindly help.

Thanks,
Riya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check the system requirements of each SQL edition you are eyeing to use, that should tell you if you can install it on Win 2003 or not.
2. Linking Access to SQL Server stores your data in SQL Server, not in the local Access Database
3. Yes, see:[Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700.aspx)

Comment: Thank You so much :) expecting some more suggestions.